# Is it possible to return a reference to the result of a static or dynamic pointer cast?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference

so let's say I have the following function:

```
    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> resourceAs() const {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(m_resource);
    }
```

This works. But what if I don't like the small overhead of creating the shared_ptr? What if I want something like this

```
    template<typename T>
    const std::shared_ptr<T>& resourceAs() const {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(m_resource);
    }
```

So, the problem here is that the compiler will be unhappy with me returning a local variable. Is there a safe way of returning a *reference* to a casted pointer of my member type? My instinct tells me no, but I'm pretty curious.

Comment: How exactly do you expect this to avoid "the small overhead of creating the shared ptr"? It's not like the `shared_ptr` does not get created until something uses the returned reference. C++ does not work this way. The `shared_ptr` ***still*** gets created, just its reference gets returned (in your proposed plan of action). So, what exactly do you think this gives you?

Comment: Well, I was hoping I could get a reference to the shared pointer that I have as a member, `m_resource`, but treat it as the casted pointer type. But what it sounds like you're telling me is that the cast itself will create a new pointer, no matter what. Is that the case?

Comment: How can you return a shared_ptr<T> without creating one?

Comment: Correct. C++ does not work this way. `shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<U>` (with U being, presumably, what this `m_resource` is) are two completely different types that have nothing to do with each other. They may be an instance of the same template, but that's irrelevant. And the only way to have one type become another different, unrelated, type in C++ is to create a new object of the new type. The reason you were getting a warning from your compiler is ***precisely because*** a new object was getting created as part of the conversion.

Comment: Makes sense, feel free to submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::static_pointer_cast<T>(m_resource);
```

This function call returns an object, and not a reference to an object.

`std::static_pointer_cast` takes an existing `std::shared_ptr` as a parameter, and creates a new `std::shared_ptr` object (for a particular purpose which is not germane). It does not return a reference to an existing `std::shared_ptr`, but a new `std::shared_ptr` object.

Consequently if what's returned from `std::static_pointer_cast<T>` is stored in some variable, then that's what happens. If not, it gets destroyed.

In C++ obtaining a reference to an object does not prevent the underlying object from getting destroyed when it normally gets destroyed (there is one pedantic exception to this rule, the temporary object lifetime extension rule, but it does not apply here).

Your attempted, alternative `resourceAs()` obtains a reference to the returned `std::shared_ptr`, and returns it. But, since this `std::shared_ptr` (that's returned from `std::static_pointer_cast`) does not actually gets stored anywhere it then gets destroyed, just like any other object that's declared local to `resourceAs()` would get destroyed, upon return from this function.

This is not something specific to `std::shared_ptr`, this is how all objects work in C++ and the same thing would happen to any other object in C++ that charters the same course:

```
class apple {

     // ...

};

apple buy_a_fruit();

const apple &what_i_bought()
{
     return buy_a_fruit();
}
```

`what_i_bought()` returns a reference to an object that's returned from `buy_a_fruit()`, but the object itself gets destroyed, leaving you with a reference to a destroyed object.

There is no valid usage of the resulting reference. Modern C++ compilers are smart enough to detect this mistake and issue a diagnostic alert.